# How to make a JS function that target it self to avoid conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make a JS function that  target it self to avoid conflict, What i want to make the script below to only target it self for example the mouseup > unbind mousemove i want it to only target the the script below it self.

```
var i = 0;
    $('#dragbar').mousedown(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         $(document).mousemove(function(e){
           $('#sidebar').css("width",e.pageX+2);
        })
     });
     $(document).mouseup(function(e){
        $(document).unbind('mousemove');
      });
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, nesting event listeners within each other is a bad idea: because you're bind a new event listener every single time mousedown is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable:

```
var canMove = false
$('#dragbar').mousedown(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  canMove = true
})
$('#dragbar').mouseup(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  canMove = false
})
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  canMove && $('#sidebar').css("width", e.pageX + 2)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dragbar').mouseup(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(document).unbind('mousemove');
});
```

should do the trick